# Codeigniter-4 Unable to forward url route with defaultnamespace

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

The url my want to make;

Default landing page : `http://localhost/Ci/tr`

The url I want to reach the admin page :
`http://localhost/Ci/tr/panel` or `http://localhost/Ci/panel`

Route.php

```
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);

$routes->group('{locale}', ['namespace' => 'App\Controllers\Frontend'], function($routes)
{
    $routes->get('/', 'Home::index' );
});
$routes->group('panel', ['namespace' => 'App\Controllers\Backend'], function($routes)
{
    $routes->get('/', 'Home::index' );
});
```

Controller file directories:
`app/Controllers/Frontend/Home.php`
`app/Controllers/Backend/Home.php`

App.php default locale `public $defaultLocale = 'tr';`

I cannot reach the main page in this way. When I change the default namespace, I cannot reach my other pages. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *main page*?

Comment: I updated the content and added a picture. Actually, I couldn't set up the route according to this structure, because I am using localization.

Answer (score 1):

1. Leave your [default namespace empty](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/routing.html#default-namespace).

> When matching a controller to a route, the router will add the default
> namespace value to the front of the controller specified by the route.
> By default, this value is empty, which leaves each route to specify
> the fully namespaced controller:

`$routes->setDefaultNamespace('');`

2. Provide a fully qualified namespace for your default controller.

`$routes->setDefaultController('App\Controllers\Frontend\Home');`

3. Adjust your routes to match your declared URLs.

```php
$routes->get('Ci/panel', 'App\Controllers\Backend\Home::index');

$routes->group('Ci/{locale}/panel', ['namespace' => 'App\Controllers\Backend'], function($routes)
{
    $routes->get('', 'Home::index' );
});

$routes->group('Ci/{locale}', ['namespace' => 'App\Controllers\Frontend'], function($routes)
{
    $routes->get('', 'Home::index' );
});
```

Comment: I couldn't find what to write in the 'ci' places for the route

Comment: @IOst , what do you mean by *'ci' places*?

Comment: `$routes->get('Ci/panel',....`

Comment: @IOst ,  You don't have to write anything. I already provided the actual routes to match your desired URLs in my answer.

Comment: @IOst , can you reach the main page with my changes in the answer provided?

Comment: I can't reach the homepage but i can reach `/panel` `/panel/login` URLs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239453/discussion-between-lost-and-steven7mwesigwa).